# Some programs don't work after restoring to new hard disk

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, data-recovery

System - Windows XP SP2 4GB Ram. Downloads stop at 99%. Same result in IE8 and Firefox 31.

Problems started after I restored a backup to new 500GB HDD using Acronis. Had no problems previously, but restore was to the same hard disk. Also a few programs(eg Spyware blaster,revo uninstaller) don't start/work now.

I think all are linked together. I cleaned up with Ccleaner and other registry & junk cleaners. I have been backing up & restoring for dozen of times(but same HD).

Comment: Did you use CCleaner, and other registry & junk cleaners, before or after you noticed this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Using Acronis, you will have to worry about losing some data. Additionally, programs like Spyware Blaster and CCleaner, while useful, sometimes have unintended consequences that they do not make you aware of outright. These programs clear histories, caches and old links which can be useful for programs to run properly.

If you really want to have everything work as it previously did, you would have needed to do a full system backup using the backup utility. Just type "ntbackup.exe" into the 'Run' dialog box and click OK.

[image]

If you simply want to cut down on the number of programs you need to install, you could use [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) to install many commonly used programs with a single installer.

If you insist on continuing your use of Acronis, note that many programs have estimated times of completion, including windows explorer, that are imperfect. Performance fluctuates throughout the transfer of data throughout your BUS. Bottlenecks often arise if other 'hungry' processes are simultaneously using your processor (chrome is one, super hungry). The programs hang at 99% because they can only increase the completion percentage so they are not truly at 99% even though that is what they display.